# attributeerror 'module' object has no attribute 'python_2_unicode_compatible'

Tags: django, python-2.7

I was trying to start my django server, but constantly getting the above error

django version is 1.5 (due to my project's backward compatibility issue, we cannot upgrate it to a newer version)

python version is 2.7.7

I've searched online and find that usually, this is due to Django version, once switched to 1.5, it'll be fine, but for me, it's still there.

Any help please?

Comment: You'll need to give more information. How are you using this? Are you importing it correctly? What does the full traceback say?

Comment: There's actually no stacktrace, the title was the only line and then it stopped. I'll add more info soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I solved this problem by creating a python27_env virtual environment and pip installed all required modules, and then it worked.

I'm guessing it's due to something got messed up in my desktop setup for python27.

Thanks guys.